# Second-order LPF not filtering correctly

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, active-filter, fft

I am trying to implement a 2nd-order Butterworth low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of 9 kHz.
As an input I was using a square wave of 12 kHz. My op-amp rails are 0 and 5 V. The sqaure wave has a 200 mV amplitude and a DC offset of 2.5 V.

[image: This is the input to the filter.]

The image above is the FFT of the input to the filter.

[image: This is the output of the filter.]

The image above is the FFT of the output of the filter. It seems that all frequency components have been filtered out, except for the harmonic at 12 kHz.

I can't seem to make sense of this. Another test I did was sending a 12 kHz sinusoid through the filter. I was expecting the output of the filter to be nothing, but I received a slightly out-of-phase 12 kHz sinusoid at the output.

I am using the following circuit to implement my filter:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the part number for the op amp you are using? Telling us it is using a single 5 V supply is useful but not enough.

Comment: It is the MCP602

Answer (score 4):

> he image above is the FFT of the output of the filter. It seems that all frequency components have been filtered out, except for the harmonic at 12kHz.

What did you expect.

A 9 kHz LPF with 20 dB per decade will only reduce the 12 kHz component of your square wave by a bit more than 3 dB.

And since you are sampling at 25 kSa/s, you shouldn't expect to see any higher harmonics (except as aliases in the 0-12.5 kHz band, which I do think are present in your scope trace) because they are above the Nyquist frequency for this sampling rate.

> Another test I did was send a 12kHz sinusoid through the filter. I was expecting the output of the filter to be nothing but I received a slightly out-of-phase 12kHz sinusoid at the output.

This is as expected. A 9 kHz, two-pole filter won't completely eliminate a 12 kHz signal, only attenuate it (and phase shift it) by a bit more than 3 dB.

If you want to completely eliminate 12 kHz components you need to choose a filter topology with a much sharper roll-off, which will require much more than 2 poles. Really to get a strong attenuation so close to your pass-band you might need to choose a notch filter rather than an LPF.

My recommendations:

- Sample at at least 240 kSa/s in order to be able see at least 10 harmonics of your signal.
- Start by measuring the unfiltered signal so you know what you're comparing your filter output with.

Comment: Also, if the transition width is too sharp, or if the filter's order is too large, the time domain response will have significant ringing, which might affect the result if not sampled after the transients have decayed. For the high order part, a Gaussian or Bessel can be used but, their passband is droopy and too soft for such steep requirements. Which leaves Chebyshev (I or II) or Cauer as candidates, and you're back to square one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I am not too well-versed with oscilloscopes so your explanation has helped a lot.